# Settting up GTM and GA4 for a new eCommerce website. Why is item information being imported into Ga4 for purchases, but not for general events?

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-datalayer, google-analytics-4

I've tried setting up GA4 & GTM for a Wix website. Because the new site has an eCommerce store, I want to be able to track events like Add to Cart, checkout, purchase etc. all with corresponding item information. I'm using this portion of this video as a guide: https://youtu.be/Yqyatmet2_w?t=501

You'll notice that for the view_item populates in both GTM and GA4. At 10:32 he highlights the view_item event in the GA4 debugger and it shows an items tab within the dashboard.

For me the items tab only populates for purchase events. I've attached a screenshot to this workflow.  [Purchase Event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3wiM.jpg)

On the other hand, for Add-to-cart, I am getting no item data at all. Just parameters and user properties. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54z9j.jpg)

Why is item data flowing properly into a purchase event but not any other kind of general event? I'd note that the parameters I've created flow into GA4 but there is no item section populating [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSXie.jpg)

I've tried creating custom parameters. I've tried creating a custom javascript variable with Chatgpt. I have no ability or knowledge as to how to change the data layer so I work with what I've got. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

GA4 requires the e-commerce events to strictly adhere to the pre-defined event names to display/report the item information. Otherwise, GA4 would not display the item details in either its e-commerce reports or DebugView even though your [Data Layer](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/ecommerce?client_type=gtm#use_a_custom_javascript_variable) or [Custom JavaScript Variable](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/ecommerce?client_type=gtm#use_a_custom_javascript_variable) or the items parameter contains the product information in your `items` array.

Here's the list of pre-defined e-commerce events ([source](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9267735?hl=en));

- `add_payment_info`
- `add_shipping_info`
- `add_to_cart`
- `add_to_wishlist`
- `begin_checkout`
- `purchase`
- `refund`
- `remove_from_cart`
- `select_item`
- `select_promotion`
- `view_cart`
- `view_item`
- `view_item_list`
- `view_promotion`

In your case, you are using the proper event name for the `purchase` event. That's the reason why you're seeing the items tab in the DebugView. But on the other hand, you are using `addToCart` instead of `add_to_cart` as your event name so the items tab is missing in the GA4 DebugView.

Comment: Thank you, Praba. Is there any way to get around misnamed events? It seems that those event names are requirements and must be reflected in the data layer.

The datalayer was automatically created by Wix. I have no developer skills, so I cannot modify the datalayer on my own.